# how. to increase the size of this image in java

Tags: android

Here is the the qr generator method. I am trying to generate a QR code in android ,the following code is generating a very small size image .if I try to increase the size from 500 to 700 its terminating. How to increase the size of that image  in java.

global variables

```
 Bitmap bitmap ;
        public final static int QRcodeWidth = 500 ;
```

private void UploadFile(final String orderId) {

```
    try{
        bitmap = TextToImageEncode(orderId);

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        final StorageReference mStorage = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://samyatadb.appspot.com/qrcode");

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

        //==============storing image to storage=====================//
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

        UploadTask uploadTask = mStorage.child(user_id).child(String.valueOf(orderId)).putBytes(data);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                downloadURL = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                Log.e("auth", "onSuccess: "+downloadURL);

                String imgpath = downloadURL.toString();
                Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                DocumentReference newqr = db.collection("Orders").document(orderId);
                data.put("ImageQR",imgpath);
                newqr.set(data, SetOptions.merge());

                Map<String, Object> data1 = new HashMap<>();
                DocumentReference newqr1 = db.collection("Orderers").document(user_id).collection("OpenOrders").document(orderId);
                data1.put("ImageQR",imgpath);
                newqr1.set(data1, SetOptions.merge());

                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Qrcode.this,"Your Order was Completed...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                taskSnapshot.getMetadata();
            }
        });
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    catch (WriterException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

xml code

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Comment: why are you compressing the bitmap?

Comment: for quality.is there any alternative?

Comment: do not compress bitmap if you dont want to decrease the quality of your image. and do not fix the width and height of your imageview in xml layout